# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isDone')

Tags: javascript

The functionality works just fine, however, I get this error in the console when clicking the trash icon while deleting the todo item.

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isDone')
        at TodoList.done_undone (script.js:68)
        at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (script.js:104)
    done_undone @ script.js:68
    (anonymous) @ script.js:104
```

Here is the link to the live page: https://sarahschlueterportfolio.z22.web.core.windows.net/todolist.html

Here is my code:

HTML

```
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <div class="todoHeader">
            <h1>My To Do List</h1>
            <input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="Things to be done..." />
            <span class="addButton" id="add_button">Add</span>
        </div>
        <ul id="todoListItems">
        </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
```

JS

```
    const todoObjectList = [];
    
    class TodoList {
        constructor(item){
            this.ulElement = item;
        }
    
        add() {
            const todoInput = document.querySelector("#userInput").value;
    
            if (todoInput == "") {
                alert("Please enter an item.")
            } else {
                const todoObject = {
                    id : todoObjectList.length,
                    todoText : todoInput,
                    isDone : false,
                }
            
            todoObjectList.unshift(todoObject); 
            this.display();
            document.querySelector("#userInput").value = ''; 
            }
        }
    
        done_undone(x) {
            const selectedTodoIndex = todoObjectList.findIndex((item) => item.id == x);
            todoObjectList[selectedTodoIndex].isDone == false ? todoObjectList[selectedTodoIndex].isDone = true : todoObjectList[selectedTodoIndex].isDone = false;
            console.log(todoObjectList[selectedTodoIndex].isDone);
            this.display();
        }
    
    
        deleteElement(z) {
            const selectedDelIndex = todoObjectList.findIndex((item) => item.id == z);
            todoObjectList.splice(selectedDelIndex,1);
            this.display();
        }
    
        display() {
            this.ulElement.innerHTML = "";
            
            todoObjectList.forEach((objectItem) => {
                
                const liElement = document.createElement("li");
                const delButton = document.createElement("i");
                
                liElement.innerText = objectItem.todoText;
                liElement.setAttribute("data-id", objectItem.id);
                
                delButton.setAttribute("data-id", objectItem.id);
                delButton.classList.add("far", "fa-trash-alt"); 
    
                liElement.appendChild(delButton);
    
                delButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    const deleteId = e.target.getAttribute("data-id");
                    personalTodoList.deleteElement(deleteId);
                })
                liElement.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    const selectedId = e.target.getAttribute("data-id");
                    personalTodoList.done_undone(selectedId);
                })
                if (objectItem.isDone) {
                    liElement.classList.add("checked");
                }
                this.ulElement.appendChild(liElement);
            })
        }
    }
    
    const listSection = document.querySelector("#todoListItems");
    
    personalTodoList = new TodoList(listSection);
    
    document.querySelector(".addButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
        personalTodoList.add()
    })
```

I have tried looking up different solutions. One recommended putting the script at the bottom of my html instead of the top, that made no difference.

I'm fairly certain there is something wrong with the line of code before the console log in the done_undone method.

Any insight on how to clear this error would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

when you click `delete` you are removing element by id

```
 deleteElement(z) {
     const selectedDelIndex = todoObjectList.findIndex((item) => item.id == z);
     todoObjectList.splice(selectedDelIndex,1); // element is removed from the array
     this.display();
 }
```

but done_undone is called inside of `this.diaplay()` in the next row

```
  done_undone(x) {
    const selectedTodoIndex = todoObjectList.findIndex((item) => item.id == x);
    // selectedTodoIndex here is -1 because element is already removed
 
    // add this condition to check if element is present in the array
    if (selectedTodoIndex !== -1) { 
      todoObjectList[selectedTodoIndex].isDone == false ? 
      todoObjectList[selectedTodoIndex].isDone = true : 
      todoObjectList[selectedTodoIndex].isDone = false;
    }
  }
```